# How can i resize a compressed image when uploading to database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**I have compressed images and now i want to resize them before move to temp files.**

```
 $query=mysqli_query($con,"select max(id) as pid from products");
    
                    $result=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                    $productid=$result['pid']+1;
                    $dir="images/productimages/$productid";
                    
                if(!is_dir($dir)){
                        mkdir("images/productimages/".$productid);
                    }
    
        $file_name = $_FILES["productimage1"]["name"];
        $file_type = $_FILES["productimage1"]["type"];
        $temp_name = $_FILES["productimage1"]["tmp_name"];
        $file_size = $_FILES["productimage1"]["size"];
        $error = $_FILES["productimage1"]["error"];
        if (!$temp_name)
        {
            echo "ERROR: Please browse for 1st file before uploading";
            exit();
        }
    
        $file_name2 = $_FILES["productimage2"]["name"];
        $file_type2 = $_FILES["productimage2"]["type"];
        $temp_name2 = $_FILES["productimage2"]["tmp_name"];
        $file_size2 = $_FILES["productimage2"]["size"];
        $error2 = $_FILES["productimage2"]["error"];
        if (!$temp_name2)
        {
            echo "ERROR: Please browse for 2nd file before uploading";
            exit();
        }
        $file_name3 = $_FILES["productimage3"]["name"];
        $file_type3 = $_FILES["productimage3"]["type"];
        $temp_name3 = $_FILES["productimage3"]["tmp_name"];
        $file_size3 = $_FILES["productimage3"]["size"];
        $error3 = $_FILES["productimage3"]["error"];
        
        $file_name4 = $_FILES["productimage4"]["name"];
        $file_type4 = $_FILES["productimage4"]["type"];
        $temp_name4 = $_FILES["productimage4"]["tmp_name"];
        $file_size4 = $_FILES["productimage4"]["size"];
        $error4 = $_FILES["productimage4"]["error"];
        
        $file_name5 = $_FILES["productimage5"]["name"];
        $file_type5 = $_FILES["productimage5"]["type"];
        $temp_name5 = $_FILES["productimage5"]["tmp_name"];
        $file_size5 = $_FILES["productimage5"]["size"];
        $error5 = $_FILES["productimage5"]["error"];
       
    
        function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality)
        {
            $info = getimagesize($source_url);
            if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
            elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);
            elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
            imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
            //echo "Image uploaded successfully.";
        }
        if ($error > 0)
        {
            echo $error;
        }
        if ($error2 > 0)
        {
            echo $error;
        }
        if ($error3 > 0)
        {
            echo $error;
        }
        if ($error4 > 0)
        {
            echo $error;
        }
        if ($error5 > 0)
        {
            echo $error;
        }
    
        else if (($file_type == "image/gif") || ($file_type == "image/jpeg") || ($file_type == "image/png") || ($file_type == "image/pjpeg"))
        {
            $filename = compress_image($temp_name, "images/productimages/$productid/" . $file_name, 50);
            $filename2 = compress_image($temp_name2, "images/productimages/$productid/" . $file_name2, 50);
            $filename3 = compress_image($temp_name3, "images/productimages/$productid/" . $file_name3, 50);
            $filename4 = compress_image($temp_name4, "images/productimages/$productid/" . $file_name4, 50);
            $filename5 = compress_image($temp_name5, "images/productimages/$productid/" . $file_name5, 50);
            
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Uploaded image should be jpg or gif or png.";
        }
```

When i'm trying to upload images(Resolution=5312*2988) it can't upload but when i upload low resolution images they all can be uploaded...So Can anyone help me to resize images according to my code or only resize according to my code...please

Comment: When you uploaded images with low resolution, data was lost, and it is impossible to resize them to a bigger size without loosing quality of the image.

Comment: BTW: If you a resizing the images in your PHP code, than you will have the full image (in high resolution!) server-side.... So, why do you think "it can't upload" ??